# SQL to retrieve userid's from a json from a column in a table

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a table with columns `dep_id` and `dep_value`.

`dep_value` has the data which is JsonData and it looks like this :

```
{
    "users": [{
        "uid": "0"
    }, {
        "uid": "1"
    }, {
        "uid": "2"
    }]
}
```

I need a sql which can extract all the values .. 0,1,2

I tried using regex in SQL but I am not sure how to pattern match in SQL.

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_count(dep_value,'uid') as user_count 
    FROM ( 
        select dep_value from users where dep_id = '123'
    )
;
```

I used this SQL to get the count of uid, similarly I need to get what uid's they are.

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: I corrected the json

Comment: Are you using Oracle 12? If so I'll post an answer that uses the `JSON_TABLE` function and we can see if that works for you.

Comment: we are using oracle 11.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to 12c, the module `apex_json` is useful to parse JSONs without relying on Regular expressions. Please refer to this answer to find a good [**example**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40633973/7998591) of the `APEX_JSON` module in action .

If your requirement is limited to only parse all the available `uid`s from the json string regardless of what depth they reside within the JSON, a Regex solution like this may be used.

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(dep_value,'"uid" *?: *?"(\d+)"',1,level,null,1) as user_count 
     from users where dep_id = 123
 connect by level <= REGEXP_COUNT(dep_value,'"uid" *?: *?"(\d+)"')
 and prior dep_id = dep_id          -- You may skip these 2 lines while 
  and prior sys_guid() is not null; --running for single, unique dep_id
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a87a857c0008a6e4c09d1cf49b2b4753)

Comment: Thanks Kaushik, but this query is running forever and it fails with timeout.

Comment: i used connect by PRIOR  dep_id =  123  worked, instead of uid, can you please give me regex for the word userID

Comment: @JavaCommitment : This answers your original question. If you think it worked, please consider accepting it. If you have any new request, preferably ask a fresh question.